# Mysql how to get all hierarchical of my table categories

Tags: mysql

my tables :

**category**
[image]

**category_xref**
[image]

how to list all my categories ?

**There are several levels of sub-categories**

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't enough information given to provide a good solution. Assuming you want to join both tables on Category_ID.  You can do something like the below:

```
select c.category_ID, c.Name, c.description, x.display_order
  from category c
  join category_xref x
    on x.category_id = x.category_id
 order by x.display_order;
```